# Button click on Access form adds data to a table for specific column

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a MS Access Form with a CWTButton
I am trying to fill the Table "Raw Data" column "CWT" with a "Yes" when it is clicked.
I'm really limited on my knowledge of programming so any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub CWTButton_Click()
INSERT INTO Raw Data (CWT)
VALUES ("Yes");
End Sub
```

I also tried

```
Private Sub CWTButton_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set re = db.Raw Data
rs.AddNew
re("CWT").Value = "Yes"
rs.Update
End Sub
```

Fixed code thanks to @Gustav

```
Private Sub CWTButton_Click()

Dim Sql As String

Sql = "INSERT INTO [RawData] ([Date], Staff, Species, Location, Length, Fish_ID, Comment, CWT) VALUES ('" & Me!Date.Value & "', '" & Me!Staff.Value & "', '" & Me!Species.Value & "', '" & Me!Location.Value & "', '" & Me!Length.Value & "', '" & Me!Fish_ID.Value & "','" & Me!Comment.Value & "','Yes');"
CurrentDb.Execute Sql
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub CWTButton_Click()

    Dim Sql As String
    
    Sql = "INSERT INTO [Raw Data] (CWT, Fish, Location) VALUES ('Yes', '" & Me!Fish.Value & "'," & Me!Location.Value & ");"
    CurrentDb.Execute Sql

End Sub

' or:

Private Sub CWTButton_Click()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("[Raw Data]")
    rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("CWT").Value = "Yes"
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    
End Sub
```

For fields of DateTime ([Date]) or numbers (Length, ID), use no quotes:

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO [RawData] ([Date], Staff, Species, Location, Length, Fish_ID, Comment, CWT) VALUES (#" & Format(Me!Date.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd" & "#', '" & Me!Staff.Value & "', '" & Me!Species.Value & "', '" & Me!Location.Value & "', " & Me!Length.Value & ", " & Me!Fish_ID.Value & ",'" & Me!Comment.Value & "','Yes');"
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav ! The first one works. The second causes a debug. The only issue with the first one is that, it makes the rest of my table blank except for the CWT. So now the rest of my inputs don't show up but the CWT says "Yes."

Comment: You must pass values for all fields you wish to be not blank (_Null_).

Comment: Ok @Gustav . Tried searching how to pass values in other columns but not quite getting an answer. So these other fields are already being filled in with things, I have to specifically tell the operation to pass over those other columns? Lets say columns "Fish" and "Location" is already filled in. How do I bypass them?

Comment: It sounds like you have a form bound to the table. Then you don't need all this; just set the control bound to CWT to "yes".

Comment: The form is definitely unbound. It has unbound in the text boxes within Design view.

Comment: Then we are back to: _You must pass values for all fields you wish to be not blank (Null)._ See expanded answer, please.

Comment: Thank you so much. I fiddled with what you gave me for a few hours since there was a syntax error for a while and I just couldn't figure it out. Now realized I was using a reserved word and didn't bracket it. I edited my post for the fixed code. Thanks again so much!

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered. Also, see my note on values for non-text fields.